# How to add image to window tile using tkinter?

Tags: python, windows, user-interface, tkinter

I am using python (3.7) and am building an app with it. I am using `tkinter` to build the gui. How do i remove the python icon from the tile in the taskbar, I want to put in my own icon.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your icon file has to be at the same directory of the program.`.iconbitmap('filename.ico')` is the command for this.
More detail at (https://www.codecupboard.com/2017/11/tkinter-title-bar-)

Example down below:

```
import tkinter as tk
mywindow = tk.Tk()

mywindow.iconbitmap('file.ico')  
mywindow.mainloop()
```

Comment: _"Your icon file has to be at the same directory of the program"_ - that is not true. It can be anywhere.

Comment: I know that, but i don't know how to do it that is why i say it like that.Thanks for reminding me i will look into it later.

Comment: Nah...its not working. Although i am getting the icon in the title bar, i am not getting the icon in the taskbar

Comment: Instead of just posting a new answer, just update the old one.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by creating a new shortcut to the python.exe or pythonw.exe file, (option available in Window's explorer right-click menu), then right click the shortcut, select properties, and change target to:

```
"C:\Path\to\Python.exe" "Absolute\or\relative\path\to\file.py"
```

Then select change icon (still in the properties window), and select your .ico file. Executing the program from this shortcut will automaticaly set the selected icon as taskbar and window icon.

Note though that by executing set shortcut, instead of clicking directly your .py file, the current working directory will be the one of python.exe, and not of your file, you can change that too in the shortcut's properties window, in the "start in" entry field (underneath target), or by using the python methods **os.getcwd()** to find the current working directory and **os.chdir(path)** to set it

Comment: If i share the .exe file with someone, the icon will not be consistent on his device will it be?

Comment: İ don't think it will work but you should try it to know.